# How can I check if an object has a time value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
a = '12'
```

I want to check if this object has a time value. Let's say I do `a.try(:to_time)`. This returns an `ArgumentError`. Can I check if a value is a time value receiving a `true` or `false` response?

Comment: How would `a='12'` have a time value? It's a String with "12" in it. Do you want to know if there is a series of numbers that represent a time like '12:00'? Your question isn't very clear what you want.

Comment: @theTinMan just for the purpose of the exercise let's say 12 is an incorrect value. I am not trying to transform this into time...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a = "12"
p a.is_a?(Time)      #false
p a.class  == String #true
p a.is_a?(Object)    #true (a's class or superclass)
```

Comment: This is what I was really looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You could use `respond_to?` to check if the object responds to the method.

```
a.respond_to?(:to_time)
```

---

EDIT

It raised `ArgumentError` which I missed before. `respond_to?` helps `NoMethodError`, but not `ArgumentError`.

You should take a look of the `to_time`'s definition in order to know how many arguments and what the arguments are for that method.

Comment: if I do a.respond_to?(:to_time) it will return true.

Comment: @MariusPop: Really?  When I do `a = '12'; a.respond_to?(:to_time)` it returns `false`.

Comment: @Davidann it would be better for me if it would return false because if i try to convert it to time it raises an ArgumentError

Comment: I see what your problem now... Yours is an `Argument Error`, which means the method do exist (i.e. respond_to? returns true) but the number of arguments does not match (maybe the to_time require 1 parameter but you provide none...)

Comment: @MariusPop:  Sorry.  I meant to say 'it returns `false`'.  I updated my comment.

Comment: @Davidann you are probably using irb not the rails console. try is a rails method...

Comment: @MariusPop:  I wasn't using `try` in my example.

Comment: @Davidann sorry about that... :to_time is also a rails method so if you are using irb it could return false otherwise it returns true

Comment: Thank you for your help. I frased my question in a confusing way. Steenslag's response helps me get what I need.

Comment: @MariusPop:  Ah, Ok!  It wasn't clear to me that you were running inside of rails.

Answer (score -1):

To parse a time try using `Time.parse`:

```
irb(main):002:0> Time.parse('12:00')
=> 2012-10-04 12:00:00 -0700
irb(main):003:0> Time.parse('the time is 12:00')
=> 2012-10-04 12:00:00 -0700
irb(main):005:0> Time.parse('jan 1, 1970 11:11')
=> 1970-01-01 11:11:00 -0700
```

Notice that this fails silently:

```
irb(main):004:0> Time.parse('12 noon')
=> 2012-10-12 00:00:00 -0700
```

Answer (score -2):

It doesn't appear that there is a built in method to do this.  But you can always overload the String model. Something like -

```
    class String
       def to_time
          begin
             Time.parse(self)
          rescue Exception => exception
             return false
          end
          return true
       end
    end
```

Comment: I do not think it is a good idea to monkey patch a commonly used class like String.  Doing so can cause unintended comsequences down the line.

Comment: You're probably right, overwriting existing methods would be a bad idea (after all, that patch would obliterate the to_time function, which  you definitely wouldn't want). so you could just write it as a new method called something like can_parse_to_time?